# 2 decimal timer in swift

Tags: swift, timer

I am making a game that has a timer. I have the number increasing at intervals of 0.01 seconds but the number that comes up does not have the decimal point in it. How do I add this decimal point in? What I get after 1 second of the timer running is "100" instead of "1.00"

Here is the code I used:

```
//timer
{
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0

    countingLabel.text = String(counter)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

//------timer update-----
func updateCounter() {

    countingLabel.text = String(counter++)

    if score.text == "10" {
       timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
countingLabel.text = String(counter++)
```

with

```
counter++
countingLabel.text = String(Double(counter)/100)
```

Comment: perfect thanks that worked 100%. Just out of interest that method wouldn't allow for a number with 3 decimal places to be generated would it?

Comment: You can divide the counter by whatever number you like, including 1000, but I don't think NSTimers are fast enough to fire every 0.001 seconds if you're trying to increment by that little.

Comment: @PeterGaffney you should not use a timer to measure time. Save the start date and get timeIntervalSinceNow

Comment: use the timer only to update the user interface. You should not need more than 1/30 of second.